# LINQ - Using FirstOrDefault or DefaultIfEmpty?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I'm getting confused about how to use `FirstOrDefault` or `DefaultIfEmpty`.

The snippet below may be empty, but if it's not, I definitely want the first one.

```cs
var vThr = _context.PostThrs.FirstOrDefault(m => 
            m.ThrZero == zero 
            && m.ThrText.Substring(0,8) == "SERVICE-");
```

If it is empty, I would like the result to be "Empty". How would I do that?
I've taken some stabs at it, but I'm not sure that it's helpful to share.

EDIT: After posting, I realized that the question doesn't really work as you cannot insert a single string into the result.

Comment: After the line can you not do `return vThr ?? new PostThr();` ?

Comment: Side note: `m.ThrText.Substring(0,8) == "SERVICE-"` should probably be `m.ThrText.StartsWith("SERVICE-")`

Comment: It depends on what type of result you want. `.FirstOrDefault()` returns the **first (single) item** that fulfills while returning `null` (default) when no item fulfills. The outcome is **`T`**. For [`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-6.0), it set a default value into `IEnumerable` when the **sequence is empty**. So the outcome is **`IEnumerable`**.

Comment: @Charlieface why? better performance?

Comment: @YongShun what is the default value that it would set? or can i customize that default value in any way?

Comment: Because if there is an index on `ThrText` then the query can do a prefix search `LIKE 'SERVICE-%'` this is not possible with a substring function

Comment: The default value set requires a `T` type which is from `IEnumerable<T>`. So yes, you can customize any value as long it is a `T` type. But the question is whether your desired result is a `T` type or `IEnumerable<T>`? If just a `T`, you can just check whether the result returned is `null` and if `null`, next assign the value that you want.

Comment: @Charlieface can I do **...m.ThrText.StartsWith("SERVICE-%")** ?? cuz that would actually be better...

Comment: No need for the `%` because LINQ will translate that for you anyway. Yes that is what you should do.

Comment: @YongShun ok so yeah I know that. I was curious as to whether I had to do that or not. Ok so that actually completely answers my question here. put it up if you want the credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarize between:

| `.FirstOrDefault()` | `.DefaultIfEmpty()` |
| --- | --- |
| Query with the result of the first item that fulfills. | Query with the result of `IEnumerable`. Use to initialize a default item if the sequence is empty. |
| - If there is item(s) fulfilled, return the first `T` item. | If there is item(s) fulfilled, return at least one or more `T` items as `IEnumerable<T>`. |
| - If not, returns `default`. | - If not, the `defaultValue` parameter is used to initialize into `IEnumerable<T>`. Returns an `IEnumerable<T>` with a single item (`Count` = 1). |

So, based on your requirement, you are looking for `.FirstOrDefault()` to check the returned result is `null` and perform the following implementation.

*Didn't cover the part that you want to assign an "Empty" string to the variable when `null` and you found out that it is not feasible to do as the variable is `T` which will conflict with the type.*

---

**References**

[`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0)

[`.DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Use FirstOrDefault() it will find first matched by condition element but if not will return just null